# How to change "65→67→69" to "J7,G2,P9" in SQL/PostgreSQL/MySQL? Or use split fields/value mapper in Pentaho Data Integration (Spoon) to realize it?

Tags: postgresql, pentaho, kettle, pdi

How to change "65→67→69" to "J7,G2,P9" in SQL/PostgreSQL/MySQL? Or use split fields/value mapper in Pentaho Data Integration (Spoon) to realize it?

I use KETTLE(Pentaho Data Integration/Spoon) to insert data to PostgreSQL from other databases, I have a field with below data

```
  value
 -----------
 65→67→69
 15→19→17
 25→23→45
 19→28→98

ID  value
--------
65  J7
67  G2
69  P9
15  A8
19  b9
17  C1
25  b12
23  e12
45  A23
28  C17
98  F18
```

And how to change the above value to the below value? Is there any SQL way or KETTLE way to realize it?

```
  new_value
 -----------
 J7,G2,P9
 A8,b9,C1
 b12,e12,A23
 b9,C17,B18
```

Thanks so much for any advice.

Comment: How do you know the `19` in `15→19→17` refers to `b9` but the `19` in `19→28→98` refers to `B34`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am sorry for my type error, only one `19` refers to `b9`, there is no `B34`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming these tables:

```
create table table1 (value text);
insert into table1 (value)
values
  ('65→67→69'),
  ('15→19→17'),
  ('25→23→45'),
  ('19→28→98')
;

create table table2 (id int, value text);
insert into table2 (id, value)
values
  (65, 'J7'),
  (67, 'G2'),
  (69, 'P9'),
  (15, 'A8'),
  (19, 'b9'),
  (17, 'C1'),
  (25, 'b12'),
  (23, 'e12'),
  (45, 'A23'),
  (28, 'C17'),
  (98, 'F18')
;
```

In Postgres you can use a scalar subselect:

```
select t1.value,
       (select string_agg(t2.value, ',' order by t.idx)
        from table_2 t2
          join lateral unnest(string_to_array(t1.value,'→')) with ordinality as t(val,idx) on t2.id::text = t.val
        ) as new_value
from table_1 t1;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=34703b28fb9bc1283d7d56d24ef1caa7)

Comment: Thanks so so much for your detailed answer.